# Monitor Network Traffic in a macOS App

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift3, xcode8

I am looking for a way to programmatically monitor total "bytes/bits" at a given interval.  The information would be polled each few seconds, and plotted on a graph to give a sense of bandwidth use for a single interface in "real time".

This is something I want to do in CODE, using Swift 3/Xcode 8 - I haven't been able to figure out where to start with network monitoring etc. for the Mac using Xcode and Swift.

Ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `NSURLProtocol`. It has its caveats, and not originally meant for this, but you can achieve good results with it. You can look into setting a proxy for your app programmatically, but that has more trouble than you'd want.

Comment: Thanks Leo for the detail - would that only be able to monitor URL traffic though?  I mean, I need to be able to see a total value for everything the computer is doing regardless of the app or protocol/port being used.

Comment: Oh, you want to traffic not just your app. In that case, creating a proxy app is the best solution, I think. Use a transparent proxy type. There are many open sources.

Comment: Thanks again - yes, basically if you went to "activity monitor" on Mac, and chose the "Network" tab, there is a small section at the bottom showing all the network activity and totals etc.  The app I am working on would have something similar to that.

Comment: Check out the `man ifmib`.